# How to make own metrics in Spring Boot for prometheus

Tags: java, html, rest, prometheus, metrics

```
@GetMapping(value = "/ownMetrics")
public String ownMetrics() {
     return "ownmetrics_age{Name=\"Age\",} " + age;
}
```

I want to make my own metrics and in right format that prometheus it can read.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Micrometer](https://micrometer.io/) for custom metrics and expose it to prometheus. If you are using gradle add these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // metrics: micrometer + prometheus
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.6.6'
}
```

At your service class add a `MeterRegistry` and a `Counter`. Initiate the `Counter` and call the `incrementer` of this counter. In my example is the `bidderCallsCounter.increment();`. I defined the metric name to be `bidder.calls` and Prometheus will replace the `.` by `_`.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class YourService {
    private MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
    private Counter bidderCallsCounter;
    public YourService(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }
    private void initBidderCallCounter() {
        // CREATE A COUNTER
        bidderCallsCounter = this.meterRegistry.counter("bidder.calls", "type", "bidder");
    }
    private Stream<Flux<BidResponse>> bidResponseStreamMono(Mono<BidRequest> bidRequestMono) {
        return biddersWebClient.stream()
                .map(bidderWebClient -> {
                    // THE INCREMENTER
                    bidderCallsCounter.increment();
                    return bidderWebClient.post()
                            ....
                            .log("BidResponse: ");
                });
    }
}
```

Then after you configure your Prometheus target, access the `http://172.17.0.1:8080/actuator/prometheus` that you can see the custom metrics available. On the screenshot you can see that Prometheus scrapes the metric `bidder_calls`.

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'spring-actuator'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      # this should be the target host IP which is outside of the docker:
      # 172.17.0.1   or   "export DOCKER_GATEWAY_HOST=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')"
      - targets: [ '172.17.0.1:8080' ]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to transmit the metrics over a Method with a @GetMapping? Because, i want use Swagger UI to document it.

Comment: AFAIK it is not because it is the dependency `spring-boot-starter-actuator` that expose the metrics to outside `http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics`. Unless you rewrite your own actuator project.....

Comment: I was thinking over it and maybe if you expose the endpoint as the `actuator` does you don't need import ita dependency and only use the `micrometer`. But I never tested it...

Comment: I will try out different ways and maybe i find one where works. if i find one, then i will post it