# Is there any method to get users' metrics such as mem and cpu usage?

Tags: prometheus

I am trying Prometheus to monitor our computing server and I want to monitor users' usages in CPUs and memory.

What I want is that usages per user can be collected and queried. By "user", I mean the individuals who login and run jobs in the server.

Is there any exporter or else to achieve this?

Very thanks!

Comment: That means *UNIX users*, yes?

Comment: Yes, UNIX users

Comment: use node exporter https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/node-exporter/

Comment: @Felipe node-exporter doesn't provide such metrics on per-user basis.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have an answer using `pushgateway` from `prometheus` here in case it fits to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67770014/2096986