# How to deal with STATE using Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a usecase where I need to observe a STATE, like say MQTT status. (Say I have a rest endpoint thats sending a state either Connected or Disconnected). When the status becomes Disconnected, I need to create an alert and then send email accordingly in Prometheus. I googled a lot, but I only found metrics related information not any State related. Can this kind of usecases are doable using Prometheus tool. If so can someone explain me the Query about the same?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: First you have to create your own metric. In case you are using spring-boot take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638736/2096986 . Then you create a rule for that metric on alertmanager

Comment: @Felipe..This is not what I was looking for. I know this metrics and all. My usecase is different, i am asking something to happen based on state. Like I mentioned if my mqtt status is Disconnected, than only i need some alert to happen. I dont want any metrics like counters, gauges or timer etc.

Comment: the state is saved on the prometheus timeseries database. You just have to send your metrics there. For instance every 15 seconds you send connect or disconnect. But before that you have to create your metric. After you have your metric we can help you to create the alert rule at the alertmanager.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a string as a metric value. More info on [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/2227)

If you want to use your status "Connected"/"Disconnected", then you'll have to use them as metric label.
As there is only two possible values, then it should be ok to use label. Hovewer, be carefull when using random string as label as it will increase the metric cardinality.

Here is a [good introduction](https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key) to cardinality and its impact on performance